# Set content root ASP.NET Integration Tests with WebApplicationFactoryContentRoot

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I am writing some integration tests in ASP.NET / .NET 7 and am using a custom `WebApplicationFactory` in my test project. I want to have a custom appsettings.json to use for these tests. When I run tests it grabs my appsettings.json from the root of the API project, not my test project. I've seen a few ways to solve the problem, but I am wondering if it is best practice to either:

- Create an appsettings.integration.json file in my api project and set the environment to "integration"
- use `WebApplicationFactoryContentRootAttribute` to set the content root to `/root/tests/api.test`

Project structure and file structure below. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
public class ApiApplicationTestFactory<TProgram> : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram> where TProgram : class
{

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseStartup<TProgram>()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, cb) =>
            {
                cb.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
            }); 
    }

root
|-api
  appsettings.json
|-tests 
 |-api.test
   myapitests.cs
   appsettings.json
```